# Samples for implementing KIF

Tags: ios, automation, kif-framework

Can you please upload some sample application and code to get started? This would really help in exploring and adding more to the on-going project.

Answer (score 11):

There's a Demo Application available in the GitHub Repo, please see: 
[The Github Repo here](https://github.com/square/KIF/tree/master/Documentation/Examples/Testable)

Comment: +1 for giving an answer instead of a snotty comment.